# How to match number composed of at least 4 unique digits

Tags: regex, mariadb

I need (unfortunately it has to be done on the level of database - MariaDB actually) to verify using regular expression numbers using rule that number have to be composed of at least 4 unique digits.

Examples what i need to accomplish:

```
112233441122 is OK (made only from 1,2,3,4)
1234564222134 is OK (6 different digits)
122102111 is bad (3 digits only: 0,1,2)
91511201 is OK (5 digits)
```

I would gladly share my tries, but I am not good right now with backreferences, and not any of my puny tries got even closer to match word composed from even two different characters.
I've also tried user defined functions that count characters in string, but they are slow and not so elegant as using REGEX.

Comment: Don't forget to show your attempt

Comment: Interesting problem, but probably much better suited for a mixed approach - first a regex that ensures "digits only", then convert the result to a set of unique characters and ensure length>=4.

Comment: `^(\d)\1*+(\d)(?:\1|\2)*+(\d)(?:\1|\2|\3)*+\d+$`

Comment: @SebastianProske: Excellent solution (if one wanted to do that in a single regex) - that should be an answer, not a comment. Let's hope that OP's (unspecified, tsk, tsk) regex engine can handle possessive quantifiers.

Comment: BTW, what is the actual regex flavor?

Comment: why do you need regular expressions here? this is clearly not the case when regex is the right tool for the job

Comment: @SargeBorsch: Becasue i needed that to filter fake phone numbers from database, and it had to be done with query in mysql.
99% of such numbers were like 123123123 or 444555666.
It is certainly not the best way to solve such problems, but I had no other option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: POSIX ERE - i think, that it is regex engine used in MySQL.

Comment: MySQL regex does not support backreferences, nor `\d` construct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right. I've tried this query not knowing that PDO is actually connecting to MariaDB (and that it is such a difference). Thank you for pointing that out. I'll made proper edit to question so it will not confuse others.

Comment: Yes, MariaDB will handle the PCRE regex OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a regex engine that supports backreferences and possesive matching, you can use:

```
^(\d)\1*+(\d)(?:\1|\2)*+(\d)(?:\1|\2|\3)*+\d+$
```

The same can be done using atomic groups:

```
^(\d)(?>\1*)(\d)(?>(?:\1|\2)*)(\d)(?>(?:\1|\2|\3)*)\d+$
```

Comment: If you avoid alternations, you'll bring a significant performance boost [**`^(\d)\1*+(\d)(?>\1*\2*)++(\d)(?>\1*\2*\3*)++(\d)\d*$`**](https://www.regex101.com/r/AfOXes/1)

Comment: MySQL does not support `\d` or most of the other regexp features mentioned here.

Comment: @RickJames Well, that's unfortunate. Note that this information has been added significantly after my answer. Not sure why OP accepted it then.

Comment: _You will need MariaDB 10.0.5 or later to use this answer._  (Oracle's MySQL had not yet implemented PCRE.)

Comment: @RickJames: My fault. Neither I did properly made background check for problem, nor my question was precise enough. It seems that PDO was connecting to MariaDB actually and everything's working perfectly. And I've learnt a lesson with this question.

Comment: @SebastianProske: Your solution is perfect. I've updated my question with important details. I was not aware that those details make such difference. Sorry for confusion and thanks again.

Comment: Seeing that many upvotes for an answer that won't work in MySQL lead me to jump hard on you.  I'm glad that it is working out.  (My second comment is still important since it includes version info.)